# Access javascript variables on server php file via browser javascript

Tags: javascript, text

using javascript code in browser to access javascript variable in server php file
( the php file search a text file and returned result as a php variable, then I set that php variable as javascript variable)

```
//php file on server called data.php
<?php
$search = 'bing';
 // Read from file
 $lines = file('text.txt');

 $linea='';
foreach($lines as $line)
  {
  // Check if the line contains the string we're looking for, and print if it does
  if(strpos($line, $search) !== false) {
  $liner=explode(': ',$line);
  $linea.= $liner[1];
  }

  }

  echo 'Search returned: '. $linea;

 <script type=\"text/javascript\">
            var varxxx = $linea;
            </script>


?>


//text file on server
foo: bar
el: macho
bing: bong
cake color: blue berry
mayo: ello



//Java script code in browser. 

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET","http://.........data.php",false);
xhr.send(null); 
$Variables.setValue(5, 'varxxx');
```

I got
reference error
x is not defined

if I just run http://.........data.php    , it shows Search returned:"Bong"
it means data.php successfully returned the result, and php $linea is Bong.

so this part below in the php file is what causes the error?

```
 <script type=\"text/javascript\">
            var varxxx = $linea;
            </script>
```

or something wrong with my Javascript code in browser?

Any help is appreciated
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try "echoing" the script tag to the .html body.
You're getting this error because the variable is being created on the server side only, thats why the variable is not defined. Also I recomend you to use let instead of var, let is more secure in terms of scope.

```
 //php file on server called data.php
<?php
$search = 'bing';
 // Read from file
 $lines = file('text.txt');

 $linea='';
foreach($lines as $line)
  {
  // Check if the line contains the string we're looking for, and print if it does
  if(strpos($line, $search) !== false) {
  $liner=explode(': ',$line);
  $linea.= $liner[1];
  }

  }

  echo 'Search returned: '. $linea;

?>

// New script
<?php
   echo("<script> var varxxx = ".$linea." </script>")
?>
```